# Make DNS server know of it's ADDC server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, active-directory, bind, samba

I have a problem and haven't been able to find an answer for it on the googles, so now I ask you

I have 2 servers:

```
Server A, ubuntu 14.04, running DNS/DHCP through bind9 and isc-dhcp-server

Server B, ubuntu 14.04, running ldap/samba and is an ADDC
I used these guides to set it up: http://www.unixmen.com/openldap-installation-configuration-ubuntu-12-1013-0413-10-debian-67-2/ and http://www.unixmen.com/setup-samba-domain-controller-with-openldap-backend-in-ubuntu-13-04/
```

I also have a windows server

```
WinServer A
```

I want WinServer A to connect to the domain that Server B provides, but WinServer A uses Server A as DNS, so it can't find the ADDC of DOMAIN, because the DNS is on one server and ADDC is on another server

My question is how to let Server A know that Server B is the ADDC of the domain, so WinServer A can find it through Server A.

Really appreciate an answer

UPDATE

In my zone I have written

```
_ldap._tcp SRV 0 0 389 ServerB FQDN
```

But when i restart bind9 and try running these commands:

```
nslookup
> set type=SRV
> _ldap._tcp
```

it returns

```
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find _ldap._tcp: NXDOMAIN
```

So I tried following an example from the web(correct me if it's wrong):
    #nano /var/lib/bind/mosek.intranet.zone

```
_ldap._tcp      SRV     0       0       389     ServerB.
_kerberos._tcp  SRV     0       0       88      ServerB.
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs    SRV     0       0       389     ServerB.
_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs        SRV     0       0       88      ServerB.
ServerB                   A       xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

but still when i try to validate it via the nslookup commands adove, it gives me the error.

I went to WinServer A to try to connect to ServerB as ADDC and I noticed progress:

```
DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "mosek.intranet":

the query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc.msdcs.mosek.intranet

the following domain controllers were identified by the query:
ServerB.mosek.intranet

However no domain controllers could be contacted

Common causes of this error include:

- Host (a) or (aaa) records that map the name of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contains incorrect addresses

- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not ruinning
```

I found this error message strange though, because I have an A record of ServerB, I tried to move it before the SRV record in case it read the zone file in sequence, but still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Windows machines use SRV records in DNS to locate domain controllers. These SRV records have to be present on the DNS server that your Windows machine is looking at if you want the Windows machine to be able to locate the domain controller. In a traditional Active Directory environment, the domain controllers register and maintain their own SRV records themselves. But technically, you can create the SRV records manually yourself if you need to use a non-Microsoft DNS server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx

Comment: In my zone I have written

    ldap._tcp SRV 0 0 389 ServerB FQDN

But when i restart bind9 and try running these commands:

   nslookup
   > set type=SRV
   > _ldap._tcp

it returns

    Server:  127.0.0.1
    Address: 127.0.0.1#53
    
    ** server can't find _ldap._tcp: NXDOMAIN